# Svelte npm run dev Complier fail

Tags: javascript, web, svelte, sveltekit, termux

## Termux

### `$ npm run dev`

```
> my-app@0.0.1 dev
> vite dev

usage: vite [options]
vite: error: argument cmd: invalid choice: 'dev' (choose from 'init', 'new', 'build', 'serve')
```

Svelte complier run

Comment: there's no _question_ here that I can see. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Termux question but rather a svelte/nodejs question. However, I assume you want to run the dev server and serve your project. (This is what we typically do in our vite dev script)

Change the line `"dev": "vite dev"` in your `package.json` to `"dev": "vite"`. This will serve your project through vite's dev server.